# replace value inside node of xml file using fs-extra in Node JS

Tags: node.js, xml

I want to read specific xml tag and update it.

here is the xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <widget id="com.ionicframework.myapp450442" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>myApp</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
    </feature>
  </widget>
```

I want to fetch the value of "id" parameter from node , How can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include the code?

Comment: Hi @AndrewEisenberg, 
I have tried below code :

const data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    const result = data.replace(new RegExp(toReplace, "g"), replaceWith);
But I have to replace the value inside the node...